# How to make Azure Web App stateless

Tags: web-applications, azure, session

On Azure, Session Management can be done using Redis Cache. But this is not truly stateless.

- Is there a way to make a Web App in general, truly stateless?
- If yes, what pattern  to follow specific to Azure cloud?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question:

> Is there a way to make a Web App in general, truly stateless?

One option is to use [JSON web tokens](https://jwt.io/). However these do have drawbacks, most notably invalidation if a token becomes compromised.